# How to view password storage scheme used in OpenLDAP?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openldap, ldap-query

Currently we are using OpenLDAP Version 2.4, From what I know is default password storage scheme is SSHA.

But is there anyway by which I can view it on console, I need to send screenshot where it is mentioned that password storage scheme of our OpenLDAP is SSHA.

> **UPDATE** : olcPasswordHash attribute is not specified in any ldif files present under **cn=config** folder

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration mode, you can check if it's set :

- Using `slapd.conf` file :

  ```
  grep password-hash slapd.conf
  ```
- Using on-line configuration (OLC) :

  ```
  slapcat -n 0 -a olcPasswordHash=*
  ```

`olcPasswordHash` attribute is defined at the database level (like in `olcDatabase={<n>}<name>,cn=config`), so you won't find it directly in `cn=config.ldif` but in the corresponding ldif file. That's why you have better to use `slapcat`.

---

A **password policy** may also require cleartext passwords to be hashed. The ppolicy overlay enables this behavior via the `ppolicy_hash_cleartext` flag (cf. [slapo-ppolicy](https://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-ppolicy)) :

> *ppolicy_hash_cleartext* : Specify that cleartext passwords present in Add and Modify requests
>   should be hashed before being stored in the database.

In this case, SSHA is used if no password storage scheme is explicitly set via `password-hash` or `olcPasswordHash`, so you would just check for the flag :

- Using `slapd.conf` file :

  ```
  grep ppolicy_hash_cleartext slapd.conf
  ```
- Using on-line configuration (OLC) :

  ```
  slapcat -n 0 -a olcPPolicyHashCleartext=*
  ```

---

If the attribute is not set : [How do you set password-hash for OpenLDAP ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/571928/how-do-you-set-password-hash-for-openldap.)

Comment: That's actually the answer to the question *How to view password storage scheme* in openldap - if set. Now if it's not then set it.. (?)

Answer (score 0):

```
COLUMNS=1000 man slappasswd | grep -- -h | grep default
```

...shows on my system:

> If -h is specified, one of the following RFC 2307 schemes may be specified: {CRYPT}, {MD5}, {SMD5}, {SSHA}, and {SHA}.  The default is {SSHA}.

To see if that default is actually used throughout the database: dump all `userPassword` attributes (might need to decode base64 if ldif is used) and check that they all start with that `{SSHA}` string.